# How can I prove that this sum is invariant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I found an interesting sequence that seems to give $f(n)=n!2^n$. I wasn't able to find anything online about this, so I figured I'd try to prove this. This was a verbal sequence so I turned it into a mathematical expression. After some cancelling out, the expression left was:
$$f(n) = \sum_{x=0}^n(-1)^x\frac{(n-x+\frac12)^n}{x!(n-x)!}$$
Now, it seems that this function doesn't change at all, in fact it is always 1. If I had been able to prove this, I would have proven that the sequence I started with really gave $f(n)=n!2^n$. But I wasn't and that's why I came here. I know this is too specific of a question, so if it isn't suitable for here, please let me know where I can ask it.

Comment: Isn't $2!2^n$ just $2^{n+1}$?

Comment: Maybe you could share you calculations, even if they are not correct.

Comment: My mistake, sorry i meant $n!2^n$ edit:wrote it wrong again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that with a change of variables,

$$n!f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n{\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}(k+0.5)^n}$$.

Note that $P(X)=(X+0.5)^n$ can be written as $P(X)=n!\binom{X}{n}+\sum_{0 \leq k < n}{\alpha_k\binom{X}{k}}$ for some real numbers $\alpha_k$.

Note now that if $0 \leq l < n$, then

\begin{align*}
g(l) & :=\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l}}=\sum_{k=l}^n{(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{l}\binom{n-l}{k-l}}\\
&=\binom{n}{l}\sum_{k=0}^{n-l}{(-1)^{(n-l)-k}1^k\binom{n-l}{k}}\\
&=\binom{n}{l}(1-1)^{n-l}=0.
\end{align*}

It is easy to see that $g(n)=1$.

So $$n!f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}P(k)}=\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}{\alpha_l\binom{k}{l}}+n!\binom{k}{n}}=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}{\alpha_l\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l}}}+n!\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n}}=n!g(n)+\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}{\alpha_lg(l)}$$.

Thus, $n!f(n)=n!$ ie $f(n)=1$.

Comment: How did $(-1)^k(n-k+0.5)^n$ turn into $(-1)^{n-k}(k+0.5)^n$? Am I missing something?

Comment: I changed $k$ into $n-k$.

Comment: Please don't judge me for being unable to see what's happening here, as I don't see these in class, I just do maths for fun as learning and understanding new things is really exciting for me. So, first off: I don't see what you did with the polynomials and how it relates to $k \choose l$. Second, I don't get why when  you substitute 0 with y, you can also substitute $k \choose l$ with $n \choose l$. And lastly, how can we assume that $l=n$?

Comment: I don’t think this solves all of your questions, but does there remain something unclear apart from the polynomial decomposition?

Comment: Yeah, first: i don't get how $\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}{\alpha_l\binom{k}{l}}+n!\binom{k}{n}}=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}{\alpha_l\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{l}}}+n!\sum_{k=0}^n{(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n}}$. Second, why $g(l)=0$ and third, why isn't $g(n)=0$ when n is odd: $n \choose k$ and $k \choose n$ cancel out leaving $(-1)^{n-k}$ inside the sum, which equals 1 when n is even and 0 when it's odd?

Comment: For second and third: are you aware that $\binom{a}{b}$ is the binomial coefficient? For your first part, I change sums. These are finite so there is no theoretical obstruction. Try and write everything out (for $n=3$, say) to understand what happens.

Comment: Yes, I am aware.

Comment: Okay. So for third, $\binom{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}$ is zero unless $n=k$. Then the binomial coefficients are $1$ and $(-1)^{n-k}=(-1)^0=1$. What is your issue with $g(l)$ for $0 \leq l < n$?

Comment: How do we know n=k?

Comment: If $k <n$, $\binom{k}{n}=0$. If $k > n$, $\binom{n}{k}=0$. So the term vanishes unless $n=k$.

Comment: i still don't get anything in the definition of g(l), also when you substitute n for l, it becomes $(-1)^l \binom nl 0^0$ and $0^0$ is indeterminate?

Comment: That is why, when I substitute $n$ for $l$, I do so in the original sum.

Comment: One last question, why does $k=0$ change into $k=l$ but $n$ doesn't change into $n$?

Comment: Because when $k=0,1,\ldots,l-1$, the binomial coefficient $\binom{k}{l}$ vanishes.

Comment: Can you explain how you went from step 3 to step 4 in g(l)?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: I think yes, I've also been looking at wikipedia to understand whats going on, still haven't really got it. Ive also realized that i don't get step 2 to step 3 too.

Comment: Step 2 to step 3 is just a change of variable (instead of counting terms from $l$ to $n$, I count them from $0$ to $n-l$).

Comment: Shouldn't $\binom{n-l}{k-l} become \binom nk$ then?

Comment: No, since throughout this part $n$ and $l$ are constants.

Comment: Why did you change n to n-l as the power of -1?

Comment: Actually $k_{before}=k_{after}+l$, so this ´ust occur inside the exponent of $-1$ as well. I grouped the appearing $l$ with the $n$ to highlight the $n-l$ from the binomial theorem.

Comment: Can you also explain what you did on the last step. Also, can you tell me how that polinomial expansion works? (This is the actual final question)

Comment: Which last step? As for the polynomial expansion, the statement is the following: for any polynomial $P$ with real coefficients, degree $d$ and dominant coefficient $\lambda$, we may write $P(X)=d!\lambda\binom{X}{d}+\sum_{0 \leq k < d}{\alpha_k\binom{X}{k}}$ for some real numbers $\alpha_k$. This is proved by induction (do it when $d=2$ or $3$ to understand what happens).

Comment: The last step of $g(l)$

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you mean leading coefficient when you say dominant coefficient?

Comment: Yes, that was a mistranslation from me.

Comment: One last thing, is there a wikipedia article or something like that to read on the equality $P(X)=d!\lambda\binom Xd+\sum_{0\le k<d}\alpha_k\binom Xk$? Since i don't really get it.

Comment: Nothing specific to my knowledge. This is elementary linear algebra if you know the theory though (a basis change in the space od of polynomials with degree $d$). But have you tried examples with polynomials of degrees 2 or 3 to get what happens?

Comment: Yeah, but i dont get what happens

Comment: i don't really get how polynomials relate to linear algebra as i don't really know a whole lot about linear algebra, can you please explain?

Comment: What do you know about linear algebra? The bits I am talking about are the abstract parts, more about vector spaces, dimension and bases. As to what happens: take some degree 2 polynomial $P=aX^2+bX+c$, then $P-2a\binom{X}{2}$ is a degree $1$ polynomial, so can be written as $\beta\binom{X}{1}+\gamma$. Overall $P=2a\binom{X}{2}+\beta\binom{X}{1}+\gamma\binom{X}{0}$. Can you do it with higher-degree polynomials?

Comment: I fail to see how $P - 2a\binom X2$ would be a 1st degree polynomial.

Comment: Have you written it down?

Comment: Yes, I have written it down.

Comment: i got $aX+bX+c$ at the end but the way i did it, theres $\frac 1{(X-2)!}$ and when X<2 factorial isnt defined?

Comment: No, $\binom{X}{k} := \frac{1}{k!}\prod_{0 \leq i < k}{(X-i)}$.

Comment: Look at the definition.

Comment: i still get it. i feel sooo dumb.

Comment: Ohhh i get it...

Comment: Great! Is everything clear to you now?

Comment: Yes! Finally :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Wait, one last thing: what if X is less than the degree?

Comment: Wouldn't the expression left still be the same degree as it didnt change at all, ie $X<d,\binom Xd=0$?

Comment: Just substitute in the formula, I do not understand your concern.

Comment: Let's say $X<d$, so $d!\lambda\binom Xd=0$, then how would we represent $X^d$ since $d!\lambda\binom Xd$ is the only term with an $X^d$ in it.

Comment: $X$ is a formal indeterminate. It is not a real number.

Comment: Yeah but how would we represent $X^d$?

Comment: Do the computation and you will realize that $P-d!\binom{X}{d}$ has degree at most $d-1$.

Comment: Why? For example $\binom X5=(x)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4), \binom X4=(x)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ and so on. $\binom Xd, 0\le d\le 5$ has $X^5$ only when $d=5$

Comment: Yes, what about it? When you have a polynomial with degree $d$, you substract the appropriate multiple of $\binom{X}{d}$ to make it degree $d-1$, then you re-do it with $\binom{X}{d-1}$ and so on...

Comment: But when $X<d$ no matter what the coefficient is, it will be 0 and the degree won't change.

Comment: But $X$ is NOT a real number. It is a FORMAL indeterminate. Look at this (in «Binomial coefficients as a basis for the space of polynomials » ) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: Wikipedia says that $d!\lambda\binom Xd$ should instead be $0.5^d$ (for our case at least)?

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning? Where does Wikipedia state that?

Comment: My reasoning was wrong.(but I still don't get it)

Comment: Write any polynomial $P$ with leading coefficient $\lambda$ and degree $3$. Then $P(X)-3!\binom{X}{3}$ has degree $2$, right? So you can write it as some $\alpha\binom{X}{2}+\beta\binom{X}{1}+\gamma\binom{X}{0}$, right?

Comment: Yes, but what i dont get is what happens when $X<d$

Comment: Also, isn't $\alpha_l$ dependent on $k$? Then how could we move it to the front?

Comment: M. Ward: how many times do I have to write it? $X$ is not a real number. $X < d$ has no meaning. The coefficients going with the lower-order binomial coefficients are here to make sure that the identity remains true, no matter what value is substituted for $X$.

Comment: Ohhh ok. Now I get it. Sorry for all the questions with obvious answers.